# In left- or right-rotation, where did those conventions for the directions come from?

Tags: arrays, collections, rotation

Generally, left rotation moves elements towards the start of the array, and right rotation goes towards the end. Why does left corresponds with start and right the end?

I remember seeing tape-like diagrams with the start to the left propagating rightward. I was going to say that was the origin in a paper I’m about to write, but I technically don’t know the actual origin.

Comment: You just wrote your question left to right. Besides asking for something that looks quite obvious, how’s that a programming problem?

Comment: I don’t know if Western-culture reading order is the actual reason; we’re both guessing. Does anyone know who coined these terms?  I’m not sure which programming-related exchange is best for historical questions.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether the reason is Western-culture reading order or xyz, whose order stems from the Western-culture reading order. But perhaps, it’s abc, which is also the reason for the Western-culture order. Perhaps, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science is the right place…